# Why are Gantz weapons slow to take effect?

Tags: gantz

I was watching the Live Action film of *Gantz* and noticed that it seems weird that after firing, the effects of a shot fired from a Gantz weapon is slow to occur, e.g.,

- when the players who killed the Child Onion Alien attack the Adult Onion Alien, the Adult Alien shields himself with one of the players with each shot but it takes several seconds before the player's body explodes
- when fighting the Buddhist Statue Aliens, there is a part where Kei shoots a limb of one of them (I think the giant one that Kannon deployed) which was going to punch him into the ground. Even after shooting it, the alien's fist continues to come toward Kei and if the delay had been longer, he could have been crushed

To me, this seems like a design flaw in the guns as it appears that the target of the shot can still move and possibly attack before it feels the effects of the attack and more so, the aliens seems to be able to react in real-time to the attacks (e.g., the Adult Onion Alien and Kannon shielding itself with its swords the moment Kei shoots).

So if the aliens can react in real-time to shots fired by Gantz Weapons, why is there a delay to the effects of such shots?

Comment: Haven't started reading this one yet but it looks like it was never mentioned why in the manga too: https://gantz.fandom.com/wiki/List_of_Gantz_Equipment . Only reason I can think of is maybe to raise the difficulty of the missions to make them more interesting and exciting.

Comment: i dont remember the source but it was said due the amount of energy compressed. Similar to the attacks from Oka against Nura with the powerfull suit. Also, the weapon can "follow target" with the another buttom, so first you "ensure", then you "shoot" unless you want to automatically shoot after "ensure" withput pressing the second buttom

Answer (score -1):

There are two options with the gantz weapons:

1.- shoot
2.- ensure

[spoiler]

> Ih the part when they fight with dinosaurs or when they are going to kill Tae Kojima they said that if you want to avoid the waiting time to shoot or if you want that shot follows target, you have to "ensure" first >!

Comment: Can you elaborate how these 2 options are related to the delayed effects of a shot?